# How to create a multisg account on Geth server?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, multisignature, sendrawtransaction

As you know, multisig wallets are more secure approach in financial cryptocurrency businesses. In my researches, I found out how can I create a multisig wallet in Bitcoin blockchain using [this link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Multisignature). Now, I wonder to know how can I create such mechanism in a Geth server?
I've checked many web pages but couldn't find any appropriate article in this regard.

Comment: You can do this using [Gnosis MultiSigWallet contract](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol), for example. It has nothing to do with Geth server though (what does "create a multisig account on Geth server" even mean???).

Comment: Thank you @goodvibration. Do you confirm that the principle of making MultiSig accounts are the same as what is mentioned in the link provided in my question?

Comment: It is an interesting question. The Parity Ethereum and Binance Smart Chain Client supports integration to Gnosis and Consensys  basedMultiSig Wallet.